# Meaning of 大振り in boxing

Tags: translation, meaning, words, manga, sports

I know 大振り is usually used in baseball to refer to a big swing of the bat, but what is its meaning in boxing? I found it in the following sentence from a manga in which a boxer is being encouraged by its trainer:

> お前のパンチは当たれば倒せるパンチなんだ！ただし勢いにのまれての**大振り**は御法度だ！コンビネーションから繋いでいけ。

I think it refers to a fast and strong punch, but why is it considered a negative thing in this case? I would be grateful if you also could correct my translation and explain the general meaning of the sentence. My attempt:

> Your punches can knock him down if you manage to hit him! But don't
>   overdo it and avoid fast punches! Start from the combinations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

大振り is not fast. It refers to [a strong/heavy but slow punch](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Punch), which tends to give the opponent a chance to dodge or counter-attack. Unlike jabs, 大振り cannot be chained to a next movement, either. I think 大振り usually has a negative connotation like this one. 勢いに飲まれる is an idiom meaning "to be overwhelmed", "to lose one's cool in the heat".

Comment: thank you for your answer! Could you also explain that 繋ぐ at the end? Does it refer to doing one combination after another?

Comment: @Marco It's just "to chain" as in "chain a combo."